# Python - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, typeerror

For some reason this piece of script is returning the error: "TypeError: string indices must be integers"; and I cannot see what's wrong. Am I being stupid and overlooking an obvious mistake here? I can't see one for the life of me!

```
terms = {"ALU":"Arithmetic Logic Unit"}
term = input("Type in a term you wish to see: ")

if term in terms:
    definition = term[terms]
    sentence = term + " - " + definition
    print(sentence)
else:
    print("Term doesn't exist.")
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, do I feel stupid! Thanks all for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want it this way: `definition = terms[term]`

Answer (score 3):

This line `definition = term[terms]` is trying to get a character out of the string `term`. You probably just typoed, and want

```
definition = terms[term]
                 ^ here, reference the dict, not the string
```

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing the string `term` instead of the dictionary `terms`. Try:

```
definition = terms[term]
```

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally swapped the variables. Change this:

```
definition = term[terms]
```

To this:

```
definition = terms[term]
```