# errors parsing json objects using python3.7, unable to access key values

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a python lambda function which receives posted data. The function looks a bit like this:

```py
import json
import ....


def handle(event, context):

    if event["body"]:
        posted_data = json.loads(event["body"])
        print(posted_data)
        print(posted_data["email"])
        print(posted_data.get("email"))
```

The line `print(posted_data)` prints my json object like this:

```
{
    "tel": "078723646",
    "message": "jsd fljxdisfbv lskdjnildufv nlksjfg",
    "email": "my@selg.om"
}
```

The line `print(posted_data["email"])` gives me this error:
`[ERROR] TypeError: string indices must be integers`

The line `print(posted_data.get("email")` give this error:
`[ERROR] AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

Yet, when I open a console, run python, and do this:

```py
>>> obj = {"tel": "078276353", "message": "uisdjy df jdslfj lsdjf fb", "email": "tetet@gdgdg.lo"}
>>> type(obj)
```

The response I get is: 
`<class 'dict'>`
So, I'm a little confused as to whether it's a dictionary or a string.

What I need to do is to access each of the values in the object.
 I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084821/1711789), but that had the effect of reversing the `json.loads`
I also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337344/python-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers), but that did not assist.   I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351239/object-has-no-attribute-get) but it doesn't seem to be relevant to my case.

After a suggestion from @brunns I inserted `print(type(posted_data))` after `posted_data = json.loads(event["body"])` and discovered that posted_data is in fact a string.

I was expecting `json.loads(event["body"])` to convert the json object to a python object. How do I go about retrieving the values in the object?

Comment: Try `print(type(posted_data))` before the line which fails.

Comment: Thanks @brunns, it's a string `<class 'str'>`. So `json.loads` didn't convert it to a python object. I will amend my question.

Comment: Show us the output of `repr(event["body"])`.

Comment: repr(event["body"]) outputs `'"{\\"tel\\": \\"0789374298347\\", \\"message\\": \\"kjsd bfkdjf vskdjfv df\\", \\"email\\": \\"gfgfg@hhh.cd\\"}"'`

Comment: It looks like the body has been converted to JSON twice, with the equivalent of `body = json.dumps(json.dumps(data))`. See what happens if you call `json.loads()` twice. If that fixes it, that means the the code posting the data should be fixed. Is it possible you're using something like jquery, and posting the data like `json=JSON.stringify(data)`? Some web libraries will automatically encode the JSON for you.